# Would it be grammatically-correct to omit "much" from "how much you've been missed"?

Tags: grammar

Would it be grammatically correct to omit the word "much" from the following phrase?

> How much you've been missed.

Would the resultant sentence "***how you've been missed***" be grammatically correct? If so, would it sound natural?

Answer (score 2):

> How you've been missed.

is fine, either used as an exclamatory sentence, sometimes preceded by ***oh,*** or as an object clause. For example:

> And *how you've been missed*. Every day Mr. Gonzalez has been on the phone begging for you. ([*A Confederacy of Dunces: A Novel*, John Kennedy Toole](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Confederacy_of_Dunces/WM6OztAsYWQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22how%20you%27ve%20been%20missed%22&pg=PA416&printsec=frontcover)). - ***exclamation***

or

> “Kristýna, is it really you?” “I hope so.” “You'll never know *how you've been missed*. ([*The Trade*, Thomas Kirkwood](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Trade/qk5E5Loi_xsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22how%20you%27ve%20been%20missed%22&pg=PT40&printsec=frontcover)) - ***direct object***